# In a network based only on switches are packet collisions possible?

Tags: networking, switch-statement, collision, packet

It's more of a theoretical question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

In a network built only using switches are packet collisions possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about networks, not coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using switches only decreases collision probability, except in case there's a microsegmentation, where each computer has its own port and you have a connection without collisions. This is because in this way you have a point to point full duplex connection between nodes and there's a collision impossibility.

Comment: Assuming a 1 gigabit switch, if you have 2 nodes sending data at 1 gigabit each to node that can only receive at 1 gigabit, is there collision, or does the switch silently drop some frames?

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  Imagine a network of 100 computers connected via dedicated links to a switch.  If 99 of them are sending packets at top speed to the other 1, collisions are guaranteed to occur.

Comment: Is that really a collision though? Normally both sides can detect a collision when it happens and resend after a random delay. The switch is going to drop somebody's data, but I'm not sure it counts as a collision.